# ARM Assembly - Function that scans an integer array with certain amount of entries and returns the maximum value in the array

Tags: assembly, arm

Function returns in int8_t, integer array in int8_t, and number of entries is in uint32_t so it would look like this

int8_t arrayMaxValue(int8_t array[], uint32_t entries)

I've tried doing this this way but it keeps returning a 0

```
arrayMaxValue:
    MOV R2, R0
    MOV R0, #0
    
arrayMaxValueLoop:
    LDR R3, [R2], #4
    CMP R3, R0
    BGT updateLoop
    SUBS R1, R1, #1 
    BNE arrayMaxValueLoop
    BX LR
    
updateLoop:
    MOV R0, R3
    SUBS R1, R1, #1 
    BNE arrayMaxValueLoop
    BX LR
```

Comment: Very similar bug to [ARM Assembly - Return number of negative values in an array(x) containing number of entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69868806) - you're loading 4 bytes at once, but int8_t is only 1.  Also, are the values all signed negative?  In that case the 0 initializer is the max out of what you had your loop look at.

Comment: Signed or unsigned? You are saying `int8_t`, but is seems you initialize the value with 0, and load 32bit values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ldrb    r2, [r0], #1    // ldrsb if signed  
    mov     r3, #0          // #-128 if signed
1:
    cmp     r3, r2
    movlo   r3, r2          // movlt if signed
    subs    r1, r1, #1
    ldrbgt  r2, [r0], #1    // ldrsbgt if signed
    bgt     1b

    mov     r0, r3      
    bx      lr
```

Comment: Why would you want the load to be conditional on having not found a new max?  I think that's going to make `r1` get to zero before the pointer gets to the end of the array.  Especially with `ge` instead of `ge`, since you skip loading on equal, and they will be equal after `mov`

Comment: @PeterCordes The CPSR `ldrbgt` refers to is set by `subs`. It's a common way of hiding memory load latency on ARM by preloading the value for the next iteration conditionally. There were times where branch took 3 cycles.

Comment: Oh right, silly me.  Neat trick, as long as the data dependency between them doesn't defeat parallelism that would otherwise exist.  Fine with OoO exec; the counter can run ahead.  (Peeling the last iteration to allow an unconditional load could decrement before the loop so it falls through one earlier.)